# encoding while reading csv files

Tags: python, pandas, csv, encoding

I'd like to merge df1 and df2 on a 'name' column.
 Each dataframe is built from a seperate csv file, respectively csv1 and csv2.

A name in df1 is **'Šarūnas Marčiulionis'** and in csv1 file it is **'Ĺ arĹ«nas MarÄŤiulionis'**.
 In csv2 it is **'Šar?nas Marčiulionis'** which gives me **'\x8aar?nas Marèiulionis'** in my df2.

Of course, these are the same person's names and I'd like to merge on it.
Is there a way while reading csv files to get the same output in my data frames?
Any general encoder that would transform names from csv into letters of only english aplhabet?
Naturaly, there are more names like that in my data.

Comment: So `df1` is correct, yeah? I see there's a Lithuanian basketball player with that name. In that case, you're creating `df2` with the wrong encoding, but what does the question mark represent in `csv2`? The file may be corrupted. Please post the data as bytes. See [mre] for more info. Also, you're opening `csv1` with the wrong encoding, but that's beside the point.

Comment: BTW, please read [ask] for tips like how to write a good title.

Comment: try `cp775` or `iso8859_4` / `iso8859_13`  instead of `utf-8`

Comment: You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case: the former example `print('Šarūnas Marčiulionis'.encode('utf-8').decode('cp1250'))` returns `Ĺ arĹ«nas MarÄŤiulionis` and in the latter one `print('Šarūnas Marčiulionis'.encode('cp1250','replace').decode('cp1252'))` shows `Šar?nas Marèiulionis`…

Comment: I spent some more time with these files. It turns out it was excel changing these symbols in foreign names on saving the csv2 file. I saved csv2 as a .txt file and it worked without use of different encoding. Remark from @wjandrea on question mark was crutial.